# minimal checks to find repeats in a list

Tags: algorithm, math, repeat

Given a sequence (d1, d2, ..., dn), I want to evaluate the product (1 - Dij) for all i != j where Dij = 1 if di = dj and 0 otherwise.

The code I have only checks Dij when i

```
prod = 1;
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) {
    for (int j=i; j<=n; ++j) {
        prod *= (1 - Dij);
    }
}
```

I know I can stop when I get Dij=1, but what I'm trying to do is get a minimal expression of the Dij's to check. This way I have one expression and then I can use difference sequences and evaluate it. So I know that I can do `i<j` instead of `i != j`. So I want to expand out this product and get something like this for n=3:

```
(1 - D12) (1 - D13) (1 - D23) = 1 - D12 - D13 - D23 + D12*D13 + D12*D23 + D13*D23 - D12*D13*D23
```

But there is more that I can do. This expression is actually always equal to

```
1 - D12 - D13 - D23 + 3 * D12*D13 - D12*D13*D23
```

My questions are:

1. Why is D12 * D13 = D12 * D23? This is always true (meaning it doesn't matter what the d sequence is) but I don't really get why because it seems to me that this means D13 = D23 which isn't always true (it depends on the d sequence). This is the relation that helps make the expression smaller.
2. How can I find all the relations like this and get a minimal expression? Is the expression above minimal? I don't even know.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The DXY are like a truth table. For D12*D13 == 1 you need d1==d2 and d1==d3, in which case, trivially d2==d3 (ie D23=1 too)

Comment: why do you calculate the product based on Dij-s, why don't you do it by di-s?

Comment: because i want a generic expression that i can use for lots of different sequences later

Comment: I guess `1- D12 - D13 - D23 + 2 D12*D13` is an answer for your point 2)

Comment: yes, that works! but how to do i find this in general for bigger ns?

Comment: @Daniel Well Always ... `DXY * DXZ * DYZ == DXY * DYZ`

Comment: then maybe i can always get is down to just Dij and Dij * Dkl terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to determine if D contains any duplicates or not. Ultimately, that requires you to compare every entry with each other, which is simply enumerating all unique combinations of two elements. That ends up being `N*(N-1)/2`. You can do a little better by sorting D first and then searching for duplicate adjacent pairs (`O(N*log(N)`), or, assuming you are sticking to a bounded range of integers, you can reduce it to linear time with a bit vector, or if you are feeling adventurous, a radix sort.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer 1 for you. Consider these two cases:

**Case 1: `D13 = D23`**

Here you can just multiply by `D12` on both sides to get `D12 * D13 = D12 * D23`.

**Case 2: `D13 != D23`**

This means that either `d1 = d3` XOR `d2 = d3` but **not both**. Therefore we know that `d1 != d2`. This implies that `D12 = 0`. Therefore

```
D12 * D13 = 0 * D13 = 0 = 0 * D23 = D12 * D23
```

The problem with your logic when you think this implies `D13 = D23` is that you cannot divide by `0`, and `D12` might be `0` (as always happens in the second case).

---

Your second question is interesting, and I do not know the answer off the top of my head, but here are some observations that may be helpful.

Draw the numbers `1, 2, ..., n` in a row:

```
1  2  3 ... n
```

Given an expression `D_(i1,j1) * D_(i2,j2) * ... * D_(ik,jk)`, make an arc from `i1 to j1` and `i2 to j2` and so on. This turns that row into a graph (vertices are numbers, edges are these arcs).

Each connected component of that graph represents a subset of the number `1, 2, ..., n`, and taken as a whole this gives us a [set partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of `{1, 2, ..., n}`.

**Fact:** Any two terms that have the same corresponding set partition are equal.

Example:

```
D12 * D23 = D12 * D13

               ---------
              |         |
1 -- 2 -- 3 = 1 -- 2    3
```

Sometimes this fact will mean the degree is the same, as in the case above, and sometimes the degree will decrease as in

```
D12 * D13 * D23

 ---------
|         |
1 -- 2 -- 3
```

The upshot is that now you can express the product (1 - Dij) as a sum over set partitions:

```
\prod_{i<j} ( 1 - Dij ) = \sum_{P set partition of \{1,2,...,n\}} c_P * m_P
```

where the monomial term is given by

```
mP = mP1 * mP2 * ... * mPk
```

when `P = P1 union P2 union ... union Pk` and if `Pi = { a < b < c < ... < z }` then

```
m_Pi = Dab * Dac * ... * Daz
```

Finally, the coefficient term is just

```
c_P = \prod (#P1)! (#P2)! ... (#Pn)!
```

Having worked this out, I'm now certain this belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how to use inclusion exclusion to find the minimal expression? I don't really know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't followed the math, but isn't this something you would code using a hashtable, or possibly even a sparse bit-array if you know the size of the di are bounded?  Just iterate over the list, filling in your data structure with a "1" at the position corresponding to the value of di - if it's already 1, return 0.  If you complete (in n steps), return 1.  It should be O(n).